# After installing php 7.2.1 on CentOS 6.9, directadmin says php 7.2.1 is installed but apache is still using older version of php

Tags: php, apache, centos6, php-7.2

I installed php-7.2.1 on CentOS 6.9 and both **# php -v** and **directadmin** say it's **7.2.1**. The *System Information* window in directadmin says:

```
Apache 2.4.29   Running
DirectAdmin 1.52.1  Running
Exim 4.87   Running
MySQL 5.5.31    Running
Named 9.8.2rc1  Running
sshd    Running
dovecot 2.2.25 (7be1766)    Running
pure-ftpd 1.0.42    Running
Php 7.2.1   Installed
```

However apache is using still the previously installed php version **php-fpm56**.

How do I make apache use the newer php version? Should I delete previously installed php-fpm56 package before attempting to install the newer one?

Comment: Just try it. Normally, the configuration won't get deleted, so if removing php-fpm56 causes problems, you could just install it again. But yes, that might be the problem: `php -v` only lists the CLI version of PHP and not the one used by your webserver

Comment: Thanks! I needed to update some options in directadmin's custombuild. Now webserver uses the correct php version.

Answer (score 1):

Update your php-fpm

```
yum install php72w-fpm
```

Then Restart your Apache

```
sevice httpd restart
```